# Move speed is slower after trying to adjust scale settings in another scene with unity

Tags: c#

I've been following a tutorial to make a top down rpg in unity. Up until now, everything was going good until I tried to make a new scene, my tile map wasn't filling tiles properly like it did in the last scene so I tried to adjust scale and such to fix it. However, after scrapping the scene and going back to the original scene my character moves much slower, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here you must have to understand the frame of reference.

Suppose that if you are walking on the earth with a speed of 4 Km/Hour towards your destination, and suddenly someone had scale up the earth so that the surface area of the earth increased and your destination distance also increase if someone [your camera in the game] observing you outside earth then it will notice that you are now walking very slow compared to the previous state.

So, this what you have done in your game. You have scaled the tile map so that the area movable area increases but the speed of your player is still the same as previous one.